# A generic error occurred in GDI+ - On specific server only

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gdi+

I have the following piece of code that turns an image into a byte array to store in the database.

```
Public Function Image2Bytes(ByRef aImage As Drawing.Image) As Byte()
    Dim MemStream As New MemoryStream()
    aImage.Save(MemStream, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Return MemStream.ToArray()
End Function
```

This works fine on our local server as well as some production servers. However, on some shared hosting servers, this gives a GDI+ error as described below:

```
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. > A generic error occurred in GDI+.:

Top Stack Trace:

System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Inner Stack Trace:

System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) 
Common.Image2Bytes(Image& aImage) 
EntityClass.Validate() 
Logo.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I've seen a lot of "Generic GDI+" errors here, but none of them solve this issue. For each solution I need to upload to a specific production server to test, as locally, there is no error.

Any ideas?

Comment: This questions has been answered all over the place.  The most common cause of a Generic GDI+ error is that the account saving the file does not have permissions to the directory that it is saving to.

Comment: Have checked that it is not a permission issue.

Comment: Does this call get made from a web service or from the page itself?

Comment: From the page itself. The image is previously loaded using a file upload control and then re-sized. The image is not being save to any directory. The resulting byte array is saved in the database.

Comment: At what point are you getting this error? is it at the aImage.Save or after the return?

Comment: As you can see in the stack trace, it is at `aImage.Save`.

Comment: One possible reason (out of many) is that the underlying stream, which the image was loaded from, has been closed.